# Accepting bad results

Tags: exams

I recently had to sit a series of take home assignments and they were so difficult I only really managed to solve 3/5 questions. I'm at the point of diminishing returns now and I was considering taking the "L" as it were and submitting since I can't do any more. Have you aver had a bad exam, how do you not let it get you down?

Comment: Some exams are intentionally very tough. Do you have a way to ask the prof for advice?

Comment: Sadly not, it was remotely delivered

Comment: In an undergraduate physics course, my semester-long average was about 35%. That was an 'A' in the class - the problems (homework and exams) were very tough by design and students were not expected to fully solve them. I will say I learned a great deal about how to properly set up problems.

Comment: Once had a final in my graduate years, one of my minors, there were four of us in the course. A gentleman we'd never seen came in, passed out the test, reactions were memorable: silence and groans. There were four questions. The first I could decipher, barely, the others I couldn't make heads or tails out of. Ten minutes in the guy behind me starts crying. I think the high score ended up being 30/100. More to the story than that, but yep, sometimes you perform poorly on a test.

Comment: @Aruralreader I think you're right, it's just one of those things where you end up being unlucky, sorry that happened to you

Comment: @Roberto_1986: Turned out the final was for a different course, a mix-up. The four of us were given the opportunity to retest. All's well that ends well, but I sure remember cudgeling my brain for a pretty miserable two hours.

Answer (score 3):

**Academia is not all about grades**.  Sometimes you can't finish an assignment.  Sometimes it's not worth your time.  I remember a time as a undergrad when I had an assignment worth 5% of my grade, but I realized that it would take over 20 hours to complete during an already busy period of my fourth year.  I just didn't do it.  It wasn't worth my time because the learning objectives of the assignment did not align with what I wanted of my career, I didn't have the time, and I didn't have the energy.  I look back on that now as probably one of the best decisions of my academic life.  It freed me to do so many other things that were much more urgent.

In your case, it seems that the exam is so difficult that you simply can't finish every question.  This happens.  Think of the exam as an opportunity to demonstrate what you learned and your ability to contextualize and use it.  It would be nice if we could all get perfect and demonstrate clear mastery of every subject, but that's not realistic, especially given the limited time we have to learn and demonstrate it during a standard academic course.  To bounce back from this, take it as an opportunity for growth.  Ask yourself the following:

1. Is it important to you to master the subject? Sometimes it isn't.  For instance, if it is a required course but one on a topic that doesn't interest you and is not a prerequisite for anything else...why does it matter?
2. If it is important to master the subject, what do you need to do to get there?  Remember, academia isn't all about grades.  Ostensibly the exam is an indication that you still have learning to do.  In a situation where you don't get any feedback and there are no grades, do you still intend to master this subject? If so, use the exam to inform what you are missing, and work on a plan to solve that.
3. Manage your expectations and reflect.  What are your goals?  Do you intend to get a high enough average to move forward in your academic career?  Is there  a scholarship you want? Or are you happy in this case to pass the course and be done with it?  Being honest with yourself, why were these assignments too hard?  In theory the exam is written so that an exceptional student can demonstrate their exceptionality, and an average student can achieve an average grade.  Presuming that this was the case, why didn't that work out for you?  It's easy to say it was "too hard" and that's that, but why?  Was it a time issue? Did you study the wrong things?  Did you not study because you expected to be able to look up what you didn't know?  How can you change your behaviour to avoid this in the future?

Ultimately, it's one course.  Ask any of your instructors what their grade was on a random course exam and I'll bet no one can really tell you.  They might remember "that one really hard exam" or "the exam that I thought was easy until I saw my mark", but they were able to move on from it and so can you.  Use it to get better.

Comment: Thank you for your that. Yes, the thing is I know the subject very well because it's related to my PhD project, I've just been unlucky and had a bad exam assigned. I know the theory but the questions are simply far too difficult :(

Comment: I think perhaps try to understand why the exam was so difficult.  Was it written with the expectation that you SHOULD be able to solve them all in the time allotted?  If so, you need to reflect on why you weren't able to.  On the other hand, sometimes in grad courses especially the focus isn't on the solution but the process, progress, and communication of your results.  Ask the instructor and ask if that is what was intended.  I have done a few  grad courses where it was simply impossible to answer everything on time and within the space allotted. We were evaluated on what we could finish

Comment: the course was delivered remotely so there's no way to talk to the instructor. I think it really is a case of me getting unlucky with the questions and struggling to solve them. I'm not doing to good anyway, I'm nearing burnout due to lockdown working etc.